# How to use autoDiffToGradientMatrix to solve for Coriolis Matrix in drake?

Tags: drake

I am trying to get the Coriolis **matrix** for my robot (need the matrix explicitly for the controller) based on the following approach which I have found online:

```
plant_.CalcBiasTerm(*context, &Cv_);
auto jac = autoDiffToGradientMatrix(Cv_);
C = 0.5*jac.rightCols(n_v_);
```

where `Cv_, plant_, context` are AutoDiffXd and `n_v_` is the number of generalized velocities. So basically I have a 62-joint robot loaded from URDF into drake which is a free body (floating base system). After finalizing the robot I am using the `DiagramBuilder.Build()` method and then the `CreateDefaultContext()` in order to get the context. Next, I am trying to set up the AutoDiff environment like this:

```
plant_autodiff = drake::systems::System<double>::ToAutoDiffXd(*multibody_plant);
context_autodiff = plant_autodiff->CreateDefaultContext();
context_autodiff->SetTimeStateAndParametersFrom(*diagram_context);
```

The code above is contained in an initialization setup code. In another method, which is called on update events, the following lines of code are written:

```
drake::AutoDiffVecXd c_auto_diff_ = drake::AutoDiffVecXd::Zero(62);
plant_autodiff->CalcBiasTerm(*context_autodiff, &c_auto_diff_);
MatrixXd jac = drake::math::autoDiffToGradientMatrix(c_auto_diff_);
auto C = 0.5*jac.rightCols(jac.size());
```

This setup compiles and runs, however the size of the `jac` matrix is 0, whereas I would expect 62x62. I am also extracting and then exposing the Coriolis **vector**, which is 62x1 and seems to be more or less correct. The `c_auto_diff_` variable is 62x1 as well, but all the elements are 0.
I am clearly making a mistake, but I do not know where exactly.

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you all,

Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  You need to tell the autodiff pipeline what you want to take the derivative with respect to.  In this case, I believe you want

```
auto v = drake::math::initializeAutoDiff(Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(62))
plant_autodiff->SetVelocities(context_autodiff.get(), v);
```

By calling [initializeAutoDiff](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/namespacedrake_1_1math.html#a32d860f5fd00b3004e866af6f73a1362), you are initializing the autodiff terms to the identity matrix, which is saying that you want to take the derivative with respect to `v`.  Then you should get non-zero derivatives.

Btw - I normally would use

```
plant_autodiff = multibody_plant->ToAutoDiffXd();
```

but I guess what you have must work, too!

Comment: Hi!
Thank you for your answer! I have tried to put those two line both in the initialization part and to the update part, but with no success. The ```jac``` matrix is still a matrix of size 0. I guess the problem is in my AutoDiff environment setup. I just do not really know, where it could be.

Comment: Nevermind, I actually put the code to the wrong place, my mistake. Now it seems to compile and run! Thank You very much!